# Getting an error inserting values into a table of SQLite3 DB using python3

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

Table has already been created. 
Problem arising while inserting values into it. 
Format method not working fine.

```
classroom_data = [
    {1,"Raj","M",70,84,92},
    {2,"Ajay","M",75,92,42},
    {3,"Alex","M",62,42,61},
    {4,"Smita","F",49,50,46},
    {5,"Palak","F",84,62,44}]

connection = sql.connect("classroom.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
for s in classroom_data:
    insert_statement = """ INSERT INTO classroom

                        (student_id,name,gender,phy_mks,chm_mks,math_mks)
                        VALUES
                        ({0}, "{1}" ,"{2}", {3},{4}, 
    {5});""".format(s[0],s[1],s[2],s[3],s[4],s[5])

    cursor.execute(insert_statement)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

Error:

```
TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-2e24144d045c> in <module>()
     12                         (student_id,name,gender,phy_mks,chm_mks,math_mks)
     13                         VALUES
---> 14                         ({0}, "{1}","{2}", {3}, {4}, {5});""".format(s[0],s[1],s[2],s[3],s[4],s[5])
     15 
     16     cursor.execute(insert_statement)

TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: Your elements are sets, either define them as lists or convert to lists before you pass them to sqlite. Sets are unordered, so its not applicable to ask for the nth element in a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lists instead of sets. Sets are for unordered data and hence indexing isn't available.

```
classroom_data = [
[1,"Raj","M",70,84,92],
[2,"Ajay","M",75,92,42],
[3,"Alex","M",62,42,61],
[4,"Smita","F",49,50,46],
[5,"Palak","F",84,62,44]]
```

Its better if you define it as list instead of converting as the elements may go out of order:

```
>>> classroom_data = [
{1,"Raj","M",70,84,92},
{2,"Ajay","M",75,92,42},
{3,"Alex","M",62,42,61},
{4,"Smita","F",49,50,46},
{5,"Palak","F",84,62,44}]
>>> classroom_data = [list(x) for x in classroom_data]
>>> classroom_data
[[1, 70, 'Raj', 'M', 84, 92], [2, 42, 75, 'M', 'Ajay', 92], [3, 'Alex', 42, 'M', 61, 62], [4, 'Smita', 'F', 46, 49, 50], [5, 'F', 44, 84, 'Palak', 62]]
```

Comment: Solved. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. If this helped then please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot index sets. If you want to index your items, just convert the sets in `classroom_data` to lists:

```
classroom_data = list(map(list, classroom_data))
```

or

```
classroom_data = [list(x) for x in classroom_data]
```

Or just define them all as lists to begin with.